# Is there a way to generate API Documentation in YAML (not JSON) format using springfox?

Tags: yaml, springfox

For my springboot project, I am using OpenAPI 3.0.3 and springfox(3.0.3) for API documentation. I would like to generate the API documentation in YAML format, not JSON. By default, springfox generates JSON.
I have looked into using springdoc-openapi-ui instead of springfox (springdoc has the option of YAML format), but then I have to change all annotations and so on.

I was wondering if there is a way around it for telling springfox to generate yaml instead of json.

Thank you!

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON, so the generated JSON is also valid YAML and can be loaded as such.

Comment: I know that swagger-ui for example reads both. However, the requirement is that when calling the endpoint to get the the API documentation, I need to get it in YAML format

Comment: As I said, the generated JSON *is* valid YAML. Any YAML processor will read it. There is no need for explicit support of JSON on the loading side. It just works. If you don't believe me, try pasting some JSON in a YAML processor (e.g. [here](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

- There is already a github issue with this query. Check out the discussion here for various possibilities -> https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/985
- Another approach could be to take Springfox JSON and convert it to YAML using JSON2YAML converter as in https://www.json2yaml.com/.